# LARAVEL: Data not showing on a page but works fine for other page

Tags: php, laravel, database, web

Im having a bit of a weird problem as a similar piece of code works for another page but it won't work for this, I can add to the database using my website but when trying to show the data it comes up as blank. Im not exactly sure what I am doing wrong and its starting to frustrate me, here's some code

Index.blade.php

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="{{ route('marketthreads.show', $thread->id) }}">{{ $thread->subject }}</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($thread->thread,100) }}
          <br>
          <br>
          {{ $thread->id }}
      </p>
  </div>
```

The Controller

```
    public function show(Marketthreads $marketthreads)
{
    return view('marketplace.details', compact('marketthreads'));
}
```

Web file (routes)

```
Route::resource('/marketthreads', App\Http\Controllers\MarketthreadsController::class);
```

Details.blade.php (the file im trying to show the data on)

[Details.blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVCfz.png)

As I mentioned before this works for another page that I have done and it shows the data but it pulls data from another table I don't think that matters too much

Hopefully someone can help me out, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$thread` which is `undefined`. In your controller you are passing `$marketthreads` to the view via `compact('marketthreads')`. So you should change `$thread` to `$marketthreads`